# Paginação em PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Fiz a paginação disponível no código abaixo, seguindo um exemplo aqui do stack, porém não funciona como eu preciso que é: exibir no máximo 5 registros por página e assim ir criando as outras páginas. Este código conta todos os registros da tabela, digamos que seja 8, a partir disso cria 8 páginas e 8 blocos de páginas, sendo que caberia 5 em uma e 3 em outra. Aceito sugestões de como ajustar.

```
$page     = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$limit = 5;
$offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM registros LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
$resp = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); 
$res  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resp);

$sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM registros";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2); 
$row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$total_de_paginas = $row['count'];

echo '<div>
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-right">
<li><a href="#" id="anterior"><<</a></li>';
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_de_paginas; $i++){ ?>
<li><a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(array('page' => $i)) ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
<?php }   
echo '<li><a href="#" id="próxima">>></a></li>
</ul>
</div> ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código não estava de todo errado, o problema foi que eu estava utilizando uma parte dele no local errado, segui algumas dicas encontradas na internet e aqui nos comentários. Segue abaixo o código final:

```
<?php
$page  = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$limit = 5;
$ini   = $page * $limit;                                     
$select  = "SELECT * FROM registros limit $ini, $limit";
$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);

while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<td>' . utf8_encode(strtolower($exibe['nome'])) . '</td>';
}

$sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM registros";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2); 
$row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$total_registros = $row['count'];
$num_paginas     = ceil($total_registros / $limit);
?>
<div>
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-right">
        <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $num_paginas -1?>" id="anterior"><<</a></li>
        <?php
            for($i = 1; $i <= $num_paginas; $i++){ ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $i - 1;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
        <?php }?>   
        <li><a href="index.php?page=0">>></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que além do LIMIT você precisará especificar o OFFSET, para indicar a partir de qual registro você quer trazer.

Exemplos:

- Página 1: LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
- Página 2: LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
- Página 3: LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10

O limit será sempre igual, o offset irá variar, incrementando o limit a cada página avançada.

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas tem um erro na linha 3, o nome da variável está sem uma letra no final e está faltando o ";"

Answer (score 1):

Pelos conceitos de paginação que utilizo um caminho para solucionar seu problema seria a implementação de um segundo parâmetro no LIMIT da sua consulta.

Seguindo uma lógica de raciocínio para que você implemente, imagine a seguinte situação:

- Você possui uma tabela com 8 registros e quer retornar 5 registros por vez para exibir em sua página. Considerando que sua página esteja corretamente desenhada e conseguindo mostrar os marcadores de paginação corretamente utilize esta sintaxe para buscar os registros que serão exibidos em cada página:

  SELECT "campos" FROM "Tabela" LIMIT "param1", "param2"

Na cláusula LIMIT o *param1* vai conter o primeiro registro da lista que será utilizado para sua consulta. O *param2* contem a quantidade de registros que serão retornados a partir disso.

**Exemplo:** `SELECT * FROM pessoas LIMIT 0, 5`

Com esta lógica a implementação da paginação fica simples pois na segunda página você irá retornar os dados passando para a consulta os valores de "LIMIT 5, 5". Logo a cada marcador de página o "param1" da consulta pode ser ajustado para posicionar corretamente no registro determinado para inciar a contagem para sua consulta.

Comment: Como eu vou alterando esse 'param2'?

Comment: o "param2" é estático, ele sempre será o valor 5 que é a quantidade de itens que pretende trazer para sua lista. Caso queira mostrar mais ou menos quantidades é nele que vai fazer seu ajuste. E para a última página do seu exemplo não precisa ser alterado pois já será retornado os 3 registros restantes.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente como tu indica no exemplo e continua da mesma maneira.

Comment: O exemplo que eu citei leva em consideração que sua página já esteja formatada corretamente para que se exiba a lista da pagina. Ou seja, considera que o problema esteja na consulta que fez. Faça o teste de executar o comando da sua requisição em um gerenciador de banco de dados (workbench por exemplo) e veja se o retorno está OK. Depois é somente identificar em qual local do código está de fato o seu problema (SQL ou HTML).

Comment: Fazendo um sql assim: SELECT * FROM pessoas LIMIT 0, 5 retornam 5 registros

Comment: Justamente, a ideia é ele pegar a partir do registro informado no primeiro parâmetro e contar a quantidade de itens informado no segundo parâmetro. Faça alguns testes alterando o valor do primeiro parâmetro para entender melhor os resultados retornados. Agora se consegue retornar os 5 registros sempre acredito então que o seu problema esteja na montagem de sua página.

Comment: O problema é que sempre são exibidos esses mesmos 5 registros desse limit

Comment: Se você testar o "LIMIT 0, 5" e depois fazer um "LIMIT 5, 5" os resultados devem ser diferentes. Veja se isso ocorre.