# Arredondar valor float?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um código que calcula o número de páginas baseado no número de dados que são chamados da base de dados. Mas com o código ele divide o número de dados por 5, ou seja, o número máximo permitido, mas o valor pode vir **decimal** e assim ele não consegue calcular bem as páginas. Existe alguma forma de arredondar o valor de por exemplo `3.2` para `4`?

Comment: Pode ser a função [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php)?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212227/57801

Comment: @Everson perfeito apontamento, dá pra dizer que é dup. (vixe o Rray foi mais rapido do que eu)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ponha como resposta e darei como aceite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ceil($number);
```

Se você usar:

```
ceil(3.6);
```

O resultado será **4**.